# Material UI Icons doesn't render after refresh

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, next.js, styled-components, google-material-icons

I'm having a problem with rendering the Material Ui icons. Whenever the page is refreshed the icons don't load, I need to force the change by removing the icon and saving the page, and adding the icon again.

I made all the styled components settings with Next and Material Ui, and added this link in _document:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" />
```

What can I do to fixed it?